# Use Imagick on XAMPP1.7.7 for save image

Tags: php, imagick

I have the following code block:

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('test.jpg');
echo "a";
?>
```

if $im is omitted, the result is "a" but if $im isn't omitted then the result is "". Is this because imagick isn't installed well? If that's the answer, how can I install it well for  XAMPP 1.7.7? On the net there's little information and they talk about using old versions of imagick but I don't like that idea.

Another question I have about imagick is that I want to reprocess an image and save it in my server. I have read about the use of move_uploaded_file but if I use writeimage I won't use that. Do I need to use it in a different way?

Last question: I pass an image encoded in 64 base and I decode in a php file. How can I assign the decode image to Imagick without saving it before?

Answer (score 0):

To display.

```
<?
$im = new imagick('test.jpg');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $im;
?>
```

To save

```
<?
$im = new imagick('test.jpg');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$saveToDir = "/home/";
$imageName = "image.jpg";
$im->writeImage($saveToDir . $imageName);
?>
```

Comment: Time ago I realised that Imagegick had problems with php 5.4 and because I didn't find anything I forget about it. My problem was that php didn't load imagick.dll. I can't know if your answer is correct or no because I can't try it.